# If a MATLAB function returns a variable number of values, how can I get all of them as a cell array?

Tags: matlab, function

I am writing a function to remove some values from a cell array, like so:

```
function left = remove(cells, item);
left = cells{cellfun(@(i) ~isequal(item, i), cells)};
```

But when I run this, `left` has only the first value, as the call to cells{} with a logical array returns all of the matching cells as separate values.  How do I group these separate return values into a single cell array?

Also, perhaps there is already a way to remove a given item from a cell array?  I could not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to use `()` instead of `{}` to index the cells:

```
function left = remove(cells, item)
  left = cells(cellfun(@(i) ~isequal(item, i), cells));
```

Using `()` for indexing will give you a subset of cells, while using `{}` will return the *contents* of a subset of cells as a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), and only the first entry of that list will get placed in `left` in your example.

You can check out [this MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-9) for more information on using cell arrays.

---

**EDIT: Response to comment...**

If you have an *operation* that ends up giving you a comma-separated list, you can place the individual elements of the list into cells of a cell array by surrounding the operation with curly braces. For your example, you could do:

```
left = {cells{cellfun(@(i) ~isequal(item, i), cells)}};
```

The inner set of curly braces creates a comma-separated list of the contents of `cells` that are not equal to `item`, and the outer set then collects this list into a cell array. This will, of course, give the same result as just using parentheses for the indexing, which is the more sensible approach in this case.

If you have a *function* that returns multiple output arguments, and you want to collect these multiple values into a cell array, then it's a bit more complicated. You first have to decide how many output arguments you will get, or you can use the function [NARGOUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) to get all possible outputs:

```
nOut = 3;                   %# Get the first three output arguments
%# Or...
nOut = nargout(@some_fcn);  %# Get all the output arguments from some_fcn
```

Then you can collect the outputs into a 1-by-`nOut` cell array `outArgs` by doing the following:

```
[outArgs{1:nOut}] = some_fcn(...);
```

It should be noted that [NARGOUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) will return a negative value if the function has a [variable number of output arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html), so you will have to choose the value for `nOut` yourself in such a case.

Comment: Aha!  Of course.  So what if there is a function which returns multiple values?  Is there a way to group them into a cellarray after the fact?

Comment: @kaleidomedallion: I'm not sure if you mean a *function* or an *operation* that returns multiple values, so I updated my answer to explain both.

Comment: This entirely answered my question.  Thank you greatly!