# How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?

Tags: matlab, indexing, matrix, return-value, variable-assignment

For example, if I want to read the middle value from `magic(5)`, I can do so like this:

```
M = magic(5);
value = M(3,3);
```

to get `value == 13`. I'd like to be able to do something like one of these:

```
value = magic(5)(3,3);
value = (magic(5))(3,3);
```

to dispense with the intermediate variable. However, MATLAB complains about `Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket` on the first parenthesis before the `3`.

Is it possible to read values from an array/matrix without first assigning it to a variable?

Comment: I also found the following article on this theme: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280225 Anybody has new information on this theme, will it be implemented?

Comment: This syntax actually works fine in Octave. I only discovered this issue when my colleagues who use MATLAB were having issues running my code.

Comment: MATLAB in a nutshell.

Comment: Recursive extraction also works in Scilab (http://www.scilab.org) since version 6.

Comment: the `testmatrix('magi', 5)(3, 3)` on Scilab and `magic(5)(3, 3)` on Octave both work like a charm!

Answer (score 421, accepted):

It actually **is** possible to do what you want, but you have to use the functional form of the indexing operator. When you perform an indexing operation using `()`, you are actually making a call to the [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) function. So, even though you *can't* do this:

```
value = magic(5)(3, 3);
```

You *can* do this:

```
value = subsref(magic(5), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {{3, 3}}));
```

Ugly, but possible. ;)

In general, you just have to change the indexing step to a function call so you don't have two sets of parentheses immediately following one another. Another way to do this would be to define your own [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to do the subscripted indexing. For example:

```
subindex = @(A, r, c) A(r, c);     % An anonymous function for 2-D indexing
value = subindex(magic(5), 3, 3);  % Use the function to index the matrix
```

However, when all is said and done the temporary local variable solution is *much* more readable, and definitely what I would suggest.

Comment: well what do you know! though i agree it's pretty ugly, and probably less readable than a temp-var solution. +1 for impressive obscure matlab knowledge!

Comment: That's disgusting, but a very clear answer. Good work! Should've guessed there'd be a back way into it. I'll think I'll carry on with the temp variable.

Comment: Bear in mind that the intermediate variable is still fully created though. So if the purpose is to save memory by not having to create a temporary local variable, no luck.

Comment: @SamRoberts: You can't really get around that in a strict-evaluation language like Matlab. The main reason people want this is conciseness/readability, not memory savings.

Comment: @SamRoberts: true, but it *does* save you from the burden of calling `clear` on the temporary (which no-one ever does) -- the temporary tends to stick around longer

Comment: Wonderful! I stumbled around the internet for hours to find this! I'm going to stick with python.

Comment: Hot damn.  I didn't know this was possible.  In the end, I'm still going to stick with the temp variable!

Comment: Any way to use this with `end`, as in `vectorReturningFunction()(1:end-1)`?

Comment: @knedlsepp: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out a way to get `end` to work with the `subsref` syntax I used above.

Comment: @knedlsepp - According to [docs of `end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html): "In that context, `end = (size(x,k))` when used as part of the kth index.". So I would say that the possibility of using `end` with `subsref` has a slight causality problem: because you're trying to find `size(x)` before `x` is known. However, "for the sake of freedom of shooting oneself in the foot", I suppose what you want is possible if you recursively do `subsref` (within the indexing term i.e. `subsref(...,{1:size(subsref(...))})`) and obtain the result so that you could know its size... :)

Comment: @Dev-iL: Would have been cool to have a feasible solution for this, but I think in the end I can still live without it. :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp - I managed to do this using a crazily complicated command that relies on matlab's interface with python, and python's negative-indexing ability. Here goes: `vectorReturningFunction = @()1:10; endminus = 4; double(py.array.array('d',py.ast.literal_eval(wrap_system(['python -c "import sys; print eval(sys.argv[1])[0:-int(sys.argv[2])]" ' regexprep(char(py.array.array('d',reshape(vectorReturningFunction(),1,[])).tolist()), ' ', '') ' ' num2str(endminus)]))))`. where `wrap_system()` is: `function out = wrap_system(cmd); [~,out] = system(cmd);`. If you post a question I'll explain more..

Comment: (I know this is a year-old discussion, but...)
Well, if you use the other possibility, creating a custom function (anonymous or not), you can convert any (-1, 0, inf,...) index to `end` inside the function...

Comment: This solution can be refined a tiny bit by using `substruct` like so: `subsref(magic(5), substruct('()', {3, 3}))`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - if you issue `[ subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'})) ]`, it will *not* behave the same as `[ A{:} ]`...any ideas for a workaround there?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Using the functional form for indexing appears to also require you to specify the number of output arguments you want from the function, the default being one. The output from the operation is a comma-separated list, but only the first one is captured. Any attempt to [capture multiple output arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821801/52738) would not give you a simple way to concatenate them into a vector. It's all a moot point, however, since you could probably just use [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html): `cell2mat(A)`

Comment: @SamRoberts Will it be automatically `clear`ed right after that?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa The intermediate variable will be cleared at the same time as any other variable - i.e. when it goes out of scope. That would not usually be immediately after the statement, but rather at the end of the function (although it could be different if the user does something like press Ctrl-C).

Answer (score 147):

There was just [good blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/?s_eid=PSM_3365) on [Loren on the Art of Matlab](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/) a couple days ago with a couple gems that might help. In particular, using helper functions like:

```
paren = @(x, varargin) x(varargin{:});
curly = @(x, varargin) x{varargin{:}};
```

where `paren()` can be used like

```
paren(magic(5), 3, 3);
```

would return

```
ans = 16
```

I would also surmise that this will be faster than gnovice's answer, but I haven't checked (Use the profiler!!!). That being said, you also have to include these function definitions somewhere. I personally have made them independent functions in my path, because they are super useful.

These functions and others are now available in the **Functional Programming Constructs** add-on which is available through the MATLAB Add-On Explorer or on the [File Exchange](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39735-functional-programming-constructs).

Comment: This is a slightly more general version of the second half of gnovice's answer; also good.

Comment: What about `myfunc().attr`?

Comment: @gerrit, how does at help? and the x.attr() field isn't available unless you have the database toolbox.

Comment: @T.Furfaro Huh?  If `myfunc()` returns a structure that includes an attribute `attr`, then to access `attr` currently I need to do `S = myfunc(); S.attr`.  The question is if we can have a helper function like `getattr(myfunc(), 'attr')` in analogy to the `paren` and `curly` helpers.  I don't understand what this has to do with the database toolbox.

Comment: @gerrit Sorry, total confusion ( I wasn't aware that your "attr" was arbitrary -- in the db tb there's such a field explicity defined ). I believe what you're looking for is [getfield()](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html)

Comment: I've edited in a link to the add-on containing a range of these functions, which is available through the MATLAB add-on explorer or the file exchange.

Comment: Nice; I'd just run across these two functions, and now I have a solid use case for them.

Answer (score 75):

How do you feel about using undocumented features:

```
>> builtin('_paren', magic(5), 3, 3)               %# M(3,3)
ans =
    13
```

or for cell arrays:

```
>> builtin('_brace', num2cell(magic(5)), 3, 3)     %# C{3,3}
ans =
    13
```

Just like magic :)

---

### UPDATE:

Bad news, the above hack doesn't work anymore in **R2015b**! That's fine, it was undocumented functionality and we cannot rely on it as a supported feature :)

For those wondering where to find this type of thing, look in the folder `fullfile(matlabroot,'bin','registry')`. There's a bunch of XML files there that list all kinds of goodies. Be warned that calling some of these functions directly can easily crash your MATLAB session.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I dont recall now, I guess I must have read it in some buried code ;)

Comment: The colon (:) operator must be used with apostrophes `':'` to avoid the error `Undefined function or variable "builtin"`.

Comment: @Dominik: right, say you want to slice the 2nd column, that would be: `builtin('_paren', magic(5), ':', 2)` (in certain places it does work without the quotations directly as `:` as opposed to `':'`, like when running in the command prompt directly not from inside a function. I guess that's a bug in the parser!)

Comment: I don't suppose there is some way to use `end` with this?

Comment: @knedlsepp: No, unfortunately the whole [`end`-trickery](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br1dtdk-1) doesn't work in this syntax, you'll have to be explicit in your indexing.. (Same limitation applies for most other listed answers)

Answer (score 61):

At least in MATLAB 2013a you can use [`getfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) like:

```
a=rand(5);
getfield(a,{1,2}) % etc
```

to get the element at (1,2)

Comment: This is actually a nice method. Any drawbacks?

Comment: @mmumboss: That's undocumented behaviour, this functionality may disappear without notice in future versions. Besides this no disadvantages.

Comment: As of MATLAB2017b, this functionality is documented.

Comment: How do I get a column or a row of the output? Such as `a(1, :)`. I've tried `getfield(rand(5), {1, 1:5})` and `getfield(rand(5), {1:5, 1})` which work fine, but are not elegant.

Comment: @ZRHan: You can use `getfield(rand(5), {1, ':'})`

Answer (score 17):

unfortunately syntax like `magic(5)(3,3)` is not supported by matlab. you need to use temporary intermediate variables. you can free up the memory after use, e.g.

```
tmp = magic(3);
myVar = tmp(3,3);
clear tmp
```

Answer (score 12):

Note that if you compare running times with the standard way (asign the result and then access entries), they are exactly the same.

```
subs=@(M,i,j) M(i,j);
>> for nit=1:10;tic;subs(magic(100),1:10,1:10);tlap(nit)=toc;end;mean(tlap)

ans =

0.0103

>> for nit=1:10,tic;M=magic(100); M(1:10,1:10);tlap(nit)=toc;end;mean(tlap)

ans =

0.0101
```

To my opinion, the bottom line is : MATLAB does not have pointers, you have to live with it.

Answer (score 6):

It could be more simple if you make a new function:

```
function [ element ] = getElem( matrix, index1, index2 )
    element = matrix(index1, index2);
end
```

and then use it:

```
value = getElem(magic(5), 3, 3);
```

Comment: but this is exactly what `subref` does... but in a more general way.

Comment: yes, more general way, but not friendly... to much ugly in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Your initial notation is the most concise way to do this:

```
M = magic(5);  %create
value = M(3,3);  % extract useful data
clear M;  %free memory
```

If you are doing this in a loop you can just reassign M every time and ignore the clear statement as well.

Comment: I agree that this is more concise, and clearing is a good idea in a loop, as you say, but the question was specifically whether the intermediate assignment can be avoided.

Comment: The `clear` statement will significantly slow down your code, it's better to leave it out unless `M` is terribly big and you're running out of memory somewhere.

Comment: @JoeKearney understood.  Perhaps it's my novice level of Matlab, but intermediate values are computed in every answer given, if only implicitly in some.  Is that correct?

In any case, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

To complement Amro's answer, you can use `feval` instead of `builtin`. There is no difference, really, unless you try to overload the operator function:

> BUILTIN(...) is the same as FEVAL(...) except that it will call the
>   original built-in version of the function even if an overloaded one
>   exists (for this to work, you must never overload
>   BUILTIN).

```
>> feval('_paren', magic(5), 3, 3)               % M(3,3)
ans =
    13

>> feval('_brace', num2cell(magic(5)), 3, 3)     % C{3,3}
ans =
    13
```

What's interesting is that `feval` seems to be just a tiny bit quicker than `builtin` (by ~3.5%), at least in Matlab 2013b, which is weird given that `feval` needs to check if the function is overloaded, unlike `builtin`:

```
>> tic; for i=1:1e6, feval('_paren', magic(5), 3, 3); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 49.904117 seconds.
>> tic; for i=1:1e6, builtin('_paren', magic(5), 3, 3); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 51.485339 seconds.
```

Comment: It is actually not strange: MATLAB keeps a list of defined functions, there is not that much searching to do. `feval` does the “normal” thing and therefore can make full use of this list. `builtin` must search elsewhere so it finds only built in functions. Likely this case is not optimized nearly as much as the “normal” case, because why would you put money into optimizing something not used very often?