# MATLAB: cannot call or index into a temporary array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to read data files each containing one column and 4097 rows. But my function needs total numbers of rows with even number (means 4096). So I used the MATLAB command x(2:length(x))). But my 'x' value in this command is a(:,k) and the issue is MATLAB cannot call or index into a temporary array. Any solution to this? I thank all for the support.
The code is:

```
for k = 1:9
with filename = sprintf('F00%d.txt',k);
a(:,k) = load(filename);
x = a(:,k)(2:length(a(:,k)));
w = tqwt(p,1,3,3);
[a1,a2,a3,a4]= deal(w{:});

 m(a1,1) = mean(a1);
 s(a1,1) = std(a1);
 ma(a1,1) = max(a1);
 mi(a1,1) = min(a1);
```

Comment: Why are you posting questions, receive answers and then delete the questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to split     `x = a(:,k)(2:length(a(:,k)));` into two lines as shown below:

```
temp = a(:,k);
x = temp(2:length(a(:,k)));
```

---

Please read:

1. [Indexing of a function's return](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235798)
2. [How can I use indexing on the output of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872875/how-can-i-use-indexing-on-the-output-of-a-function)