# Expression for summing all the entries of a logical matrices expressions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

To sum all the elements in a matrix you usually do

```
A = sum ( B(:) );
```

which is nice and short. However assume that we have a logical expression like this

```
B = B == 6
```

and we want to sum the elements of all the entries, then smartest way seems to be to do

```
A = sum ( sum ( B == 6 ) )
```

or

```
B = B == 6;
A = sum( B(:) );
```

Both are kind of ugly. So I was wondering is there a nicer expression?

```
A = sum ( (B == 6)(:) );
```

Would be nice but doesn't work.

Comment: A = sum ( (B == 6)(:) ); doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what is so nasty about the simple solution...

```
A = sum(B(:) == 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I recommend this, but as was shown [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it/3628885#3628885), you can actually do something like:

```
%# A = sum ( (B == 6)(:) )
A = sum( subsref(B == 6, struct('type','()', 'subs',{{':'}})) )
```