# Can properties of an object handle returned from a function be used without first assigning to a temporary variable?

Tags: oop, matlab, syntax, return, handle

I have a function that returns a handle to an instantiated object. Something like:

```
function handle = GetHandle()
    handle = SomeHandleClass();
end
```

I would like to be able to use the return value like I would if I was writing a program in C:

```
foo = GetHandle().property;
```

However, I get an error from MATLAB when it tries to parse that:

```
??? Undefined variable "GetHandle" or class "GetHandle".
```

The only way I can get this to work without an error is to use a temporary variable as an intermediate step:

```
handle = GetHandle();
foo = handle.property;
```

Is there a simple and elegant solution to this, or is this simply impossible with MATLAB's syntax?

Comment: This is very similar to [another question asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/), but in reference to indexing a returned vector.

Comment: Where does `GetBackend` come into it?

Comment: The software has a "backend" class that instantiates a number of child objects. Each child object accesses methods in other children by referencing through the backend. This requires every child to be given a copy of the backend handle. I'm looking for an alternative way that would avoid needing the handle to be passed all over. My thought was to create a GetHandle() function available on the path that would return the handle. Any other suggestions on how to do this are also appreciated.

Comment: I just realized what you meant, @nzbuu. The error was copied from my real code's error message and I forgot to change it to reflect the name I used in my example code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define static properties, you can use the [CONSTANT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/bso_zpq-1.html) keyword (thanks, @Nzbuu)

Here's one example from MathWorks (with some errors fixed):

```
classdef NamedConst
   properties (Constant)
      R = pi/180;
      D = 1/NamedConst.R;
      AccCode = '0145968740001110202NPQ';
      RN = rand(5);
   end
end
```

Constant properties are accessed as `className.propertyName`, e.g. `NamedConst.R`. The values of the properties are set whenever the class is loaded for the first time (after the start of Matlab, or after `clear classes`). Thus, `NamedConst.RN` will remain constant throughout a session as long as you don't call `clear classes`.

Comment: In relation to my comment above (in response to @nzbuu), I have used this method to solve my problem.

The "static property" I added was a function that returns the handle I am interested in. It's a bit sneaky but it lets my work this into the existing program design with little impact. Thank you.

Comment: What about constant properties?

Comment: @Nzbuu: D'oh! I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't like to disagree with Jonas and his 21.7k points, but I think you can do this using the [hgsetget](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hgsetget.html) handle class instead of the normal handle class,  and then using the [get](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hgsetget.get.html) function.

```
function handle = GetHandle()
    handle = employee();
end


classdef employee < hgsetget
    properties
        Name = ''
    end
    methods
        function e = employee()
            e.Name = 'Ghaul';
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can use the get function to get the property:

```
foo = get(GetHandle,'Name')

foo =

Ghaul
```

EDIT: It is not excactly like C, but pretty close.

Comment: Don't worry, I still keep making mistakes or overlooking stuff, despite the gold badge :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have a static property in MATLAB is as a constant:

```
classdef someHandleClass < handle
    properties (Constant)
        myProperty = 3
    end
end
```

then `someHandleClass.myProperty` will return `3`.