# Using elementwise operation and element indexing together in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write an anonymous function taking a vector `theta`  as its input and compute the sum of the fourth-squared of the first half elements of `theta`:

```
L=@(theta) sum(theta.^4(1:length(theta)/2))
```

But Matlab reports an error

```
??? Error: File: c2n9.m Line: 3 Column: 27
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

I identified the error same as the following simpler example

```
>> a=ones(1,4)

a =

     1     1     1     1

>> a.^4(1:2)
??? a.^4(1:2)
        |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

>> (a.^4)(1:2)
??? (a.^4)(1:2)
          |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

I wonder how I can make the simple example as well as the anonymous function work?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. `(a.^4)(1:2)` works in Octave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead do

```
a(1:2).^4
```

Comment: Seems that's covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it

Comment: @Ethan: your original code doesn't work because you can't index results like that.  If you were to store the output of the `.^4` operation like `temp=a.^4; temp(1:2);` it would work;

Answer (score 1):

you should do the indexing before the per-element raising to the power

instead of:

```
L=@(theta) sum(theta.^4(1:length(theta)/2))
```

try

```
L=@(theta) sum(theta(1:round(length(theta)/2)).^4)
```

note that I also added a round to take care of the case where the length of theta is odd

Answer (score 0):

Err, aren't you missing a multiplication sign at the place that the first error message points to ?  Or something else ?

Comment: There is no multiplication in my expressions. I updated my code just now.