# Directly accessing return values of e.g. xlim?

Tags: matlab, syntax

In Matlab

```
xlim
```

returns e.g. [0,1]. Now I want to access the last value of xlim directly, therefore without storing the xlim return values in a variable. Is that possible?

```
xlim(2)
```

is obviously interpreted as a function call, not as getting the value at index 2.

Any workaround on this, except the following, which involes an additional variable?

```
temp = xlim;
temp(2)
```

Comment: See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/1214731).  Personally, I like to use the anonymous function route if I need something like this.

Answer (score 3):

Since `xlim` always returns an ordered pair (as long as `xdir` is not set to `reverse`) , you can access the elements directly using the `min` and `max` functions.

Use `min(xlim)` to access the first element and `max(xlim)` for the second element.

If  `xdir` is set to `reverse`, `max(xlim)` will return the first element and `min(xlim)` the second.

Comment: although clever, it it less readable than just using a temp variable. You get my vote anyway +1

Comment: I agree on the lack of readability and also would prefer the temp variable. I just noticed the trick and wanted to share it since it meets the request of the questioner.