# MATLAB, how to evaluate multiple indices in one line?

Tags: matlab

I don't know how to explain this better than by giving you an example.

Suppose I have the following array:

```
a = magic(6)
```

And then I take a 'slice' of that like this:

```
a(:,1)
```

It will print:

```
35
 3
31
 8
30
 4
```

Now I want the first number, so I want to write:

```
a(:,1)(1)
```

Instead of:

```
b = a(:,1)
b(1)
```

Also, is there a way to do something like this (assignment and comparison, i.e. set b, then evaluate against it):

```
(b = a(:,1))(1)
```

---

Ok, here's an update with a function where it isn't trivial to use a(1, 1)

```
come_on = sprintf('%i, ', magic(3));
come_on(1:end-2)
8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2
```

Also, what if I only want the first 4 numbers on magic(3)?
It would be better to write

```
sprintf('%i, ', magic(3)(1:4))(1:end-2)
```

instead of tens of lines, MHO.

Comment: There have been a lot of questions like this lately.  [Here's a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/1214731) describing a couple of options.

Comment: tmpearce you nailed it :D, thanks dude

Comment: k sorry tm, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate indexing as `foo(1)(2)(3)`. However, you can index multiple dimensions at once. So in this case, `a(1,1)` will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, yeah in this simplified example a(1,1) gives me what I want, but there are others where that is just no possible. So there is absolutely no way to concatenate (or emulate that) indexing?