# Indexing of Matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I merge this two commands in one in Matlab?

```
Temp = diag(diag(A));
X = Temp(:)
```

Something like

```
X = diag(diag(A))(:)
```

does not work.

Comment: seems Matlab's been lagging too much in [implementing that syntax](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Coherent_syntax). It's valid in GNU Octave.

Comment: See [how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) for another solution. But really, it is more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to, you can do:

```
X = reshape(diag(diag(A)),[],1)
```

I'm not sure you gain much by doing that though!