# Accessing contents of array elements stored as values of a containers.Map object

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

I have a question with regards to accessing array elements stored as values of a containers.Map object. I have successfully created my containers.Map object where the keys are strings, and the values are zeros(1,3) arrays.

```
myHashTable = containers.Map(keys,values);
myHashTable(keyString)
```

would give me:

> ans =
>
> > > 0   0   0

What I am having trouble with is accessing values stored within these arrays at a specific index. For example trying to do this:

```
myHashTable(keyString)(1)
```

would give me the error:

> ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

How would I go about accessing the elements of an array stored as a value in the container without using another variable like:

```
tempArray = myHashTable(keyString);
tempArray(1)
```

Edit: Found an answer to the question. It has been asked before but I didn't find it in my preliminary search. Can't close my question because I I don't have the required reputation points to do so immediately. For those interested check:

[How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)