# Plot first element of vector in A^x * v in Matlab (matrix powers)

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, adjacency-matrix

I want to plot `A^x * v`, where `A` is a square matrix represent an adjacency matrix in a graph, `x` is the number of steps, and `v` is the initial vector.

My goal is to plot the first element of each resulting vector; that is, I want `A*v[1], A^2*v[1], A^2*v[1]`

I tried

```
x = 1:1:50 
y = A^x*v
plot(y(1),x)
```

But got

```
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

I understand the error, but don't understand how else to approach this problem, just going off Matlab's plot examples.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What are the dimensions of A?

Comment: A changes, but a specific case is 10 by 10.

Comment: You need to do a for loop over the x's rather than trying to do all of the exponents at once. I don't know a way to vectorize that operation.

Comment: When `A` is not a square matrix, `A^n` is not defined. Thats why the error comes.

Comment: @Parag, A is square, the problem is that x is not a scalar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an almost one liner:

```
x = 1:1:50;
f = @(z) z(1);
plot(x, arrayfun(@(n) f(A^n*v), x))
```

---

The error in what you tried comes from `A^x`: `x` cannot be a vector, it must be a scalar because `A` is a square matrix. See the [help of `mpower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

How about saving some of the computations?
To get the first element you don't need to compute the entire product `A*v`.

```
x = 1:1:50;
f = (n) A(1,:) * ( A^(n-1) ) * v; % returns a scalar - no redundant computation
plot( x, arrayfun( f, x ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

A modification to [@Simon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15059830/1714410) answer, using [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) rather than anonymous function.

```
x = 1:1:50;
s.type = '()';
s.subs = {1};
plot( x, arrayfun( @(n) subsref( (A^n)*v, s ), x ) );
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it?lq=1) about `subsref`.