# Matlab using multiple containers.Map raises an Index exceeds matrix dimensions error

Tags: matlab, dictionary

Here a sample code:

Class A:

```
classdef classA
    properties
        mapOfB
    end
    methods
        function self = classA(names)
            self.mapOfB = containers.Map();
            for i = 1:numel(names)
                self.mapOfB(names{i}) = classB(names);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Class B:

```
classdef classB
    properties
        mapTest
    end
    methods
        function self = classB(names)

            self.mapTest = containers.Map();
            for i = 1:numel(names)
                self.mapTest(names{i}) = rand(1,3);
            end
        end              
    end   
end
```

main script:

```
names = {'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'};
a = classA(names);
a.mapOfB
a.mapOfB.keys
a.mapOfB('one')
a.mapOfB('one').mapTest
a.mapOfB('one').mapTest.keys
a.mapOfB('one').mapTest('one')
```

console output:

```
a.mapOfB('one').mapTest.keys

ans = 

    'four'    'one'    'three'    'two'

a.mapOfB('one').mapTest('one')
Error using subsref
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

I don't understand why there is an index exceeds matrix dimensions error when I call a map item in a map. It is a Matlab limitation ?

Comment: Don't know the exact answer, but I guess this is somehow related two how [subsref](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) and how [indexing](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html) work in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line, which is totally equivalent to "a.mapOfB('one').mapTest('one')", does not raise the error

```
builtin('_paren', a.mapOfB('one').mapTest, 'one')
```

Therefore it's not a "real" error, but a limitation on MATLAB's syntax or implementation of containers.Map's subsref() operator.

See also [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)