# Multiple left-hand-side partial assignment in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, matrix-indexing

Consider the following matrix:

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

therefore

```
size(a)=[1,3]
```

I want to assign the second dimension 3 to variable n. What is the most efficient way?

Why are the following not working?

```
[[],n]=size(a)
```

or

```
  n= num2cell(size(a)){2}
```

Comment: Seems like the most neat way is to use a  temporary variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the simplest, and works for `a` with any number of dimensions:

```
n = size(a,2);
```

If `a` is guaranteed to have exactly 2 dimensions, you could also use

```
[ m, n ] = size(a);
```

and if you don't need the first variable, in recent versions of Matlab you can write

```
[ ~, n ] = size(a);
```

As for the things you have tried:

- `[[],n]=size(a)` does not work because `[]` is not a variable to which you can assign anything.
- `n= num2cell(size(a)){2}` does not work because you can't directly index like that in Matlab. You would need a temporary variable: `temp = num2cell(size(a)); n=temp{2}`. Or dispose of `num2cell` and do: `temp = size(a); n=temp(2)`.

Comment: The first code is the correct one. Careful about the others, `size` will return the product of the remaining dimensions if you dont specify enough output variables; example: `x = rand(5,4,3,2); [~,n] = size(x);` (`n` will be equal to 4*3*2)

Comment: if you dont know the number of dimensions, another way is to do: `[~,n,~] = size(x)` this will work even if `ndims(x)==2`. Of course `size(x,2)` is the still the preferred way.

Comment: Also, `~` doesn't work for older versions of matlab. Specifically R2009a on my laptop, not sure about other revisions.