# Select partial output of a function into a new function

Tags: matlab, data-manipulation

I have a matrix, say:

```
y=rand(100,101);
```

Now I would like to average over the first dimension, and use only part of the output (say only the odd indices) into another function. So I could do

```
ymean=mean(y,1)
```

and then

```
ymean_partial=somefunction(ymean(1:2:length(ymean)))
```

*But* my question now is (assuming it is possible): how can I do this without having to declare the 'dummy variable' `ymean`? I would like to know if there's a one-liner I could use, since this extra variable takes up a lot of memory for larger matrices (and I tend to like one-liners).

Many thanks!

Comment: Please see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it

Comment: Oh great, that's actually the general solution I was looking for, although Jonas' answer works perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you simply take the mean on the subset only?

```
ymean_subset = mean(y(:,1:2:end),1);
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't....I got stuck in a certain thinking pattern I guess. Thanks!