# Matlab, alternative to creating an extra vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, sum, cumsum

If I have this I get an error

```
sum(vector) == cumsum(vector)(length(vector))

>> Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

I know I can just do:

```
Vec1 = cumsum(mat);
sum(mat) == Vec1(length(mat))
```

which will return a logical 1.

Is there an alternative to get everything on a single line?

Comment: Why do you need to "get everything on a single line"?

Comment: I was thinking that fewer variables to accomplish the same function would be better. I guess everything looks clearer on two lines rather than one though.

Comment: This is one of those cases where two lines is better.  However, there are ways to do subscripting with the named form of the `()` operator, `subsref`.  See my answer.  It's just trivia, really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are absolutely determined to do it in one line,

```
sum(vec) == subsref(cumsum(vec),struct('type','()','subs',{{numel(vec)}}))
```

But this is a borderline abuse of [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), which is generally used for overloading the subscripting operators (i.e. `{}`, `()`, `.`) in custom classes.