# Permutations function in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, permutation

In Wolfram Mathematica，there is a function called `Permutations`(http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Permutations.html). 
It can gives all permutations containing exactly n elements.

For example: `Permutations[{1,2,3,4}, {2}]` gives

`{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 
  4}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}}`

I know Matlab have a similar function `perms`, but it only receive one parameter and gives  all possible permutations. Is there other function like Mathematica's `Permutations[list,{n}]`？

Comment: http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/combnk.html

Comment: There is one on the FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11462-npermutek/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, take a look at `nchoosek`.

If it does (which seems to be the case), there is an inefficient, ugly, but non-toolbox dependent one-liner:

```
>> unique(builtin('_paren', perms(1:4), :,1:2), 'rows')
ans =
      1     2
      1     3
      1     4
      2     1
      2     3
      2     4
      3     1
      3     2
      3     4
      4     1
      4     2
      4     3
```

(which is really [a hacked two-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16220271/1085062)).

I'd suggest you just use `combnk` from the Statistics toolbox.

Comment: +1 but I suggest you add the 2 line equivalent as well for legibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the combinations of your desired size using `nchoosek` and then permute them using `perms`. That means for permutations of length `k` from vector `v` you can use

```
A=nchoosek(v,k);
P=reshape(A(:,perms(1:k)), [], k);
```

Note that the rows of `P` will not be sorted and you can use `sortrows` to sort it:

```
P=sortrows(reshape(A(:,perms(1:k)), [], k));
```

Using your example

```
v = 1:4;
k = 2;
A=nchoosek(v,k);
P=sortrows(reshape(A(:,perms(1:k)), [], k))
```

returns:

```
P =
     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     2     1
     2     3
     2     4
     3     1
     3     2
     3     4
     4     1
     4     2
     4     3
```