# MATLAB's legendre function returns an array

Tags: matlab, math

I am working with an equation from a book and it works when I used Mathematica to solve it. It essentially contains the integral of certain orders of Legendre polynomials. E.g. P_1(x), P_2(x), P_3(x).

When I use Mathematica for a particular case e.g.

```
LegendreP[3, 0.5]
```

I get

```
-0.4375
```

which allows me to continue with my evaluation. But in MATLAB I get:

```
>> legendre(3,0.5)
ans =
-0.4375
-0.3248
5.6250
-9.7428
```

The first returned value is always correct but then it spits out... I think the other coefficients? So what I would like to do is tell MATLAB just to return the first value. Is there a way to do this without assigning it to its own variable afterwards?  Eg. something like

```
legendre(3,0.5)(1)
```

Obviously wont work because it doesn't exist in memory yet. Am I even going about this the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

Comment: Very nice, Thanks. well that answers that bit. Now I wonder if its okay to use that in big loops or should I write my own legendre function to just return the first order...?

Comment: It is always better to stick to the library because the official function is optimized. Since in this case it is not that bothering to call the libarary, I would suggest using it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it bothers you, just put `legendre` into a new function `legendre1`, so you're using the library function, but with your desired functionality.

```
function [ P ] = legendre1( n,X )
P = legendre(n,X);
P = P(1);
end
```

or implement a custom range:

```
function [ P ] = legendre1( n,X,range )
P = legendre(n,X);
P = P(range);
end
```

so `legendre1( 3,0.5,1 )` will return:

```
P =

   -0.4375
```

and `legendre1( 3,0.5,1:2 )`

```
P =

   -0.4375
   -0.3248
```

Comment: Dude, great idea! I will use that. Thanks both of you guys!

Comment: Just a minor improvement. Replace `P(1)` by `P(1,:)` since `X` can also be a vector, which would mean, that `legendre(N,X)` would return a matrix. The same for `P(range)`.