# How do you compose functions in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to chain these two functions:
1. select the third dimension of a m x n x 3 matrix
2. flatten the matrix into a (m+n) x 1 vector

Something like: `mat(:,:,1)(:)` or `(mat(:,:,1))(:)`

But this is not the correct syntax.So how do I chain these two functions together without assigning some variable to the intermediate result `mat(:,:,1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain those two indexings in Matlab. But in this case you can substitute the second indexing by a [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
reshape(mat(:,:,1),[],1)
```

If the second indexing is more complicated than just flattening the matrix, the `reshape` trick will not be applicable in general. In that case [there is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) to avoid using an intermediate variable, but it results in cumbersome and ugly code, so it's not recommended.