# Expression in arrays to get a scalar one. Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I have a vector array that contains Time values in an asceding order. With relational expressions I can obtain subset values from that array, after that I need the first value of that subset without creating new variables.
For example.
Time is an column vector, then I can use `Time(something==X)` to get a subset values of Time, but then I need the first value of `Time(something==X)`, I can't use `Time(something==X)(1)` like some programming languages u.u

Comment: See also the highest-voted matlab-tagged question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately with MATLAB you need to use temporary variables. It doesn't support this kind of indexing, though it is quite natural and I would love if they supported it.

You would have to do this:

```
x = Time(something==X);
y = x(1);
```

Octave **does** have the ability of doing this kind of indexing though.  The only way I can think of you escaping this is if you use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html).  However, if you want to use a normal vector, then you're [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL).

**EDIT: May 13th, 2014** - Referencing David's comment, it **is** possible to do this without a temporary variable, but readability is very poor.  In the end, a temporary variable is still the better way for readability and reproducibility.  Check the following SO post that he has referenced:

- [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)