# Matlab map with multiple keys or nested

Tags: matlab, containers

I am currently trying to map some data within a month depending on `'Month'`, `'week'`, `'day'`.

This means that in principle I have three keys. I thought of following solutions to the problem:

1)

`containers.Map(month,containers.Map(week,containers.Map(day,value)))`

The problem with this solutions is to reference it I must use: [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it).

And I find this solution rather "ugly".

2)

So another way would be to use a `Map` with multiple keys. The [containers documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/map-containers.html) show that only a single dimension key is allowed.

**Question:**

Do you have any trick to solve this multiple key problem?

**Update/Solution:**

I ended using a concatenated string as a key (as suggested) I added following piece of code to make the `containers.Map` as a proper multi-dimensional hashmap. Take a look below (I excluded week for simplification):

```
classdef example
properties
    myMap % Map for storage
end

methods

function obj = example()
        obj.myMap = containers.Map;
end

function obj2 = setVal(obj2,value,Month,DayType)
        key = strcat(num2str(Month),'-',num2str(DayType));
        obj2.myMap(key) = value;
    end

    function value = getValue(obj,Month,DayType)
        key = strcat(num2str(Month),'-',num2str(DayType));
       value = obj.myMap(key);
    end

end
```

Comment: If it's month/week/day shoudn't convertig to a date (which is a double) be an option? Then you have a single key.

Comment: @Daniel - I thought of that too, but I honestly don't know what format each key is in, so I went with a generic string.

Comment: @Daniel and rayryeng, take a look at the solution above. rayryeng once again thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use all three of those keys to build a single key.  I'm assuming this can be done as `Month`, `week` and `day` could be considered as unique.  There is only **one** unique combination of these per occurrence.  As such, simply take these keys and build them into single strings, then use theses as keys into your dictionary / `containers.Map()`.

Here's an example:

```
%// Test data
month1 = 'May';
week1 = 2;
day1 = 'Thursday';

month2 = 'June';
week2 = 3;
day2 = 'Friday';

month3 = 'July';
week3 = 4;
day3 = 'Sunday';

%// Define keys
key1 = [month1 num2str(week1) day1];
key2 = [month2 num2str(week2) day2];
key3 = [month3 num2str(week3) day3];

%// Build dictionary
M = containers.Map();
M(key1) = 'Hello!';
M(key2) = 'Testing!';
M(key3) = 'Yes!';

%// Now test accessing
disp(M(key1));
disp(M(key2));
disp(M(key3));
```

---

The above code will take three months, three weeks and days, convert them into strings, and use these as keys into your dictionary.  I don't know what the output type is for your purposes, so I just assigned strings.  Note that I took the numbers and used `num2str` to convert the numbers into strings to ensure compatibility with the rest of the string.  I don't know what data type `week` is (or any of the other variables in fact...), so simply use what I have and modify it for your own purposes.

I create the dictionary, then to test it, I access each of the values with each of the keys.  As expected, my output is:

```
Hello!
Testing!
Yes!
```

Comment: @SteewDK - I made a lot of assumptions, so hopefully I'm on the right track somehow.  If this doesn't help, then oops... at least I tried!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I where not able to use a date as a key since this did not match dates. However, I used your method to constrstruct a function for getting and setting data in the Map - see my update above. Once again thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new MapNested class on Matlabs File-exchange:
http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62492-mapnested-implementation-for-nested-maps--map-of-maps-

or on github:

https://github.com/RolandRitt/Matlab-NestedMap

Check it out!

The syntax for setting an value is the following:

```
NMapobj = MapNested(); %constructor;
NMapobj(key1, key2, key3) = value;
```

for retrieving:

```
value = NMapobj(key1, key2, key3);
```