# Matlab Fieldnames indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, field-names

So I have a cell array with multiple tables and I am trying to access the first column name of the table.

```
c={'table1', 'table2', 'table3'}
```

Both of the following lines gives me the error:

```
fieldnames(c{1})(1) 
fieldnames(c{1}){1}

Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

But if I do following, it works:

```
fn=fieldnames(c{1})
fn{1}
```

Is there a way to do this with one line of code and can someone please explain the error?

Comment: thanks Banana, I was just about to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it).

Generally such problems can be solved using a function call (either a dummy function that just returns the input) or you could just replace the fn{} with an explicit call to [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html):

```
subsref(fieldnames(c{1}),substruct('{}',{1}));
```

Regarding your question about why the error happens - [maybe this link could help](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/113864-error-indexing-must-appear-last-in-an-index-expression).

Comment: I get following error: 
The "subs" field for the subscript argument to SUBSREF and SUBSASGN must be a cell or character array.

Comment: I was missing {} around the `1` inside `substruct`. Should work now. You should take a look at the links I mentioned for more info.

Comment: The question @Dev-iL links to looks like exactly what you need. The anonymous function looks like a neat solution. `subindex = @(A,r,c) A(r,c); s = subindex(fieldnames(c{1}), 1, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that the follow code reproduces your data structure:

```
col1 = [1; 2; 3];
col2 = [4; 5; 6];
t1 = table(col1, col2);
t2 = table(col1, col2);
t3 = table(col1, col2);
c = {t1, t2, t3};
```

If that is the case then this should work:

```
subsref(fieldnames(c{1}),substruct('{}',{1}))
```