# Matlab - how to build functions

Tags: matlab, function, math

Matlab has the function Legendre that returns to an integer m and real number r a vector of length m+1.

Now I want to define another function fun that gives me only the first component of this vector per fixed m, so I want to define a function fun(m,r) that gives me the first component of the vector legendre(m,x). The point is that fun(m,r) should also be a function, just like legendre. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function as follows:

```
function out = fun(n,x)
temp = legendre(n,x); %// store output of "legendre" in a temporary variable
out = temp(1); %// return only desired element
```

Of course, this should be placed in a file `fun.m` within Matlab's path.

---

Alternatively, if you are feeling [hackish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it), you can use

```
getfield(legendre(n,x), {1})
```

to extract the first element of `legendre(n,x)` directly (without a temporary variable). This allows defining `fun` as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as follows:

```
fun = @(n,x) getfield(legendre(n,x), {1});
```