# Matlab making new cell array from another cell array fileds

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array `thiscells`:

```
thiscells <1*40 cell>
eacharray of thiscells is 280*3
```

I have a function (`TheFunction`) that gets input of cell array that each array is X*2

How can I send a cell array to `TheFunction` that contain only columns1,3 from each array?

I tried

```
TheFunction(thiscells{:}(:,1:2)) % tring to send only columns 1,2
```

But it didn't work

Edit:

working with (but still looking for faster way to do so):

What is did so far

```
TheFunction(makingNewCells(thiscells,2));
```

when

```
makingNewCells:
[newCells]=makingNewCells(oldCells)
for ii=1:max(size(oldcells))
  newCells=oldCells(:,[1 column]);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) and its answers may be of help - `thiscells{:}(:,1:2)` is already failing without the call to `Thefunction`, if I am not mistaken.

For cells, the problem is even worse: add to this impossibility to double-subref that even if it did what you intended it to do, this passes 40 arguments (which are all 280x2 vectors) to `Thefunction`. I doubt there are (m)any legitimate uses for a function that takes 40 arguments of the same type, instead of having those wrapped in a cell. I would probably try `doc cellfun` first.

EDIT: just to be clear, I suggest changing `Thefunction` so that it accepts a cell of 40 matrices of size 280x2), then using

```
cell_of_twocolumned_arrays = cellfun(@(x)x(:,[1 2]),thiscells)
```