# How to define a new function from a matrix function?

Tags: matlab

It is a very simple problem, though I do not know how to deal with it.

I defined a function `f(x,y)` which will return a, say, 2*2 matrix. I want to define a new function `g` whose value is the (1,1) element of `f(x,y)`. I naively tried `g=@(x,y)(f(x,y))(1,1)`, which of course failed . Please help me!

Comment: The easiest way to get the (1,1) element of a matrix is just to call `f(1,1)`. A function isn't really needed.

Comment: But `f(1,1)` will return a 2*2 matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I realize you called your function `f`. If you have a matrix `M`, you can get its `(1,1)` element using `M(1,1)`.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it). There several possible solutions are described.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :)

```
g = @(x,y)([1 0] * f(x,y) * [1 0]')
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, I'll keep that one in mind! Unfortunately not very practical for large matrices.

Comment: Of course, getfield is a proper one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`getfield`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html)

Let's define `f(x,y)` to return a 2x2 matrix

```
f = @(x,y) [1*x 2*y;3*x 4*y].^2 ;
```

Then let's define a function `g11(x,y)` which return the element {1,1} of `f(x,y)`. (and an extra function `g21` which return the {2,1} element)

```
g11 = @(x,y) getfield( f(x,y) , {1,1} ) ;
g21 = @(x,y) getfield( f(x,y) , {2,1} ) ;
```

And now:

```
>> f(3,4)
ans =
     9    64
    81   256

>> g11(3,4)
ans =
     9

>> g21(3,4)
ans =
    81
```

---

*For more fancy usage of field assignment without temporary variable, read all the nice answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)*