# Matlab: error message: ??? Bad cell reference operation

Tags: matlab

I tried to replace:

`[BB{1,1}(combs(ii,1),:) BB{1,2}(combs(ii,2),:) BB{1,3}(combs(ii,3),:)]`

by `[BB{1,1:end}(combs(ii,1:end),:)]`

but I get this error message: ??? Bad cell reference operation.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you tried:

> `[BB{1,1:end}(combs(ii,1:end),:)]`

Isn't valid because you can't index multiple cells at the same time.  I'm guessing that the reason you tried that is because you want to make work on matrices with different numbers of columns.  It's possible, but you have to use cellfun to index each cell separately.

```
cellfun(@(x)x(combs(ii,:)), BB(1,:))
```

That will let you work with matrices of any arbitrary size in the 2nd dimension.

UPDATE:

I'm not sure if I understood what you were trying to do.  In my last solution, I thought you were trying to get the entire `ii`th row of each matrix in `BB`.  Looking at the original code, there is a correspondence between the second dimension of `BB` and the second dimension of `combs`.  Here is another possibility that preserves that correspondence:

```
A = cellfun(@(x,n)x(combs(ii,n),:), BB(1,:), num2cell(1:size(BB,2)), 'UniformOutput', false);
cat(2,A{:})
```

Note that this will only work if the second dimension of `BB` and `combs` are the same size.

Comment: ??? Error using ==> cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.

Comment: Oops. Sorry.  That's because I used curly brackets instead of parentheses.  I fixed it.

Comment: Now I do not get an error message, but instead of getting a matrix 12x7 , I get a matrix 12x3 !! With [BB{1,1}(combs(ii,1),:) BB{1,2}(combs(ii,2),:) BB{1,3}(combs(ii,3),:)], I get a matrix 12x7.

Comment: I think this will fix that: cellfun(@(x,n)x(combs(ii,n),:), BB(1,:), num2cell(1:size(BB,2)))

Comment: ??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Error in ==> CC(ii,:) = cellfun(@(x,n)x(combs(ii,n),:), BB(1,:), num2cell(1:size(BB,2)));

Comment: I'm really trying, haha.  You can use `'UniformOutput',false` like the error message says, but then you will get a cell array of numerical arrays instead of a numerical array.  I updated the solution to do that and then collapse the cell array into a numerical array.  Maybe that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Alan's answer, you can copy the cell contents into a temporary double array using the [comma-separated nature](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of cell arrays and then index:

```
temp   = [BB{1,1:end}];
values = temp(combs(ii,1:end),:);
```

It would be nice if we could index the array literal itself like `[BB{1,1:end}](combs(ii,1:end),:)`, but MATLAB doesn't have nice syntactic sugar for that operation (though there is an, in my opinion, [ugly way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628885/3121310)).