# Leave out single value within vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have the following situation:

```
PA_2 = inv(T2)*[PA_0;1]
```

Where `PA_0` is a 2x1 vector and `PA_2` is a 3x3 matrix.
The answer will be:

```
[2,14903810567666;-0,722243186433546;1]
```

The problem is that i want to leave out the 1. So i want to get a 2x1 vector in stead of a 3x1 vector.

What would i have to change/edit to this line: `PA_2 = inv(T2)*[PA_0;1]` ?

Do any of you guys know the answer to my problem?

Thanks for your time,

Justin

Comment: So @Just van Til does any of the answers below helped you? If so please upvote/mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do it in one line (someone else may chime in on that) so what i would do is this

```
PA_2 = inv(T2)*[PA_0;1];
PA_2 = PA_2(1:2);
```

the **:** means range. the left is your start index and the right is your end index. You can even use this notation with matricies. Just for example

```
a = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
a(2:3,1:2)
%produces 
%ans =
%     4     5
%     7     8
```

and one more helpful tidbit, if you were using longer vectosrs/matricies you can use the end keyword. It automatically find the last index. So for your example you could do

```
PA_2 = inv(T2)*[PA_0;1];
PA_2 = PA_2(1:end-1);     %leaves out the last element
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) question which has a lot of interesting answers.

For your application the undocumented function `builtin` works fine:

```
PA_2 = builtin('_paren', inv(T2)*[PA_0;1], 1:size(T2,1)-1)
```

Note that you can't use the keyword `end` with it, so you have to use the size of T2 for instance to input the right number of elements.