# Directly getting the elements of an array/cell in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

Say I have a vector like [10,3,4], is there a way to get, for instance, the second element directly? Something like:

```
[10,3,4](2)
```

Also, if I have a cell of anonymous functions,such as:

```
funcs = {@(s) s^2 , @(s) s+5},
```

is there a way to access them in a way like:

```
funcs{2}(s)
```

(*Edit: funcs{2}(s) works. It turns out the error I got was because of something else!*)
What I want to do is to save the gradient of a function in a cell like $gradr$ and then be able to get its dot product with another vector. Something lik:

```
dot([gradr{1}(s),gradr{2}(s)],n)
```

I cannot assign each component a different name since I'll be using the numbering later.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: the answer to the first part of my question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) No, not really. You need to put `[10, 3, 4]` into a variable `a` and then get the second element `a(2)`. (You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/2586922) do it, but it's not worth it).

ii) Yes: just use `funcs{2}(2)`, or `feval(funcs{2}, 2)`.

iii) You can try something like:

```
>> inarg = 1;
>> cellfun(@(x)feval(x,inarg),funcs)
ans =
     1     6
```

Comment: So you can use `funcs{2}(s)` directly! Nice

Comment: @LuisMendo, yes, no need for `feval` there. I just put the possibility in as a lead-in to my answer to part three.

Comment: I gave funcs{2}(2) another try and the error I got was because of something else! It works fine now,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: quoting [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice)'s words, it's actually [*possible, but ugly*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/2586922). Perhaps the easiest way (described in one of the answers to the linked question) is to (ab)use [`getfield`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html):

```
>> getfield([3 4 5],{2})
ans =
    4
```

For the second part: you can use [`feval`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html):

```
>> funcs = {@(s) s^2, @(s) s+5};
>> s = 3;
>> feval(funcs{2}, s)
ans =
     8
```

or see [Sam Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29007955/2586922).

Answer (score 0):

You could use ans(2) if you're going to call the vector temporarily, otherwise, you'll better affect it to a variable.

```
>> [10,3,4]

ans =

    10     3     4

>> ans(2)

ans =

     3
```

Comment: Actually, by not putting an assignment operator there you assign it to the variable `ans`. Depending on `ans` can be acceptable for a quick calculation on the command line, but I would recommend strongly against using anything like this in a normal function or script.