# parsing KEGG information

Tags: matlab, indexing

I want to index an expression in Matlab to return only the first argument

```
new_mets{i}=strsplit(mets{j},' (');
ans  = 
'Anteisopentadecanoylcardiolipin'    'B. subtilis)'
```

like this:

```
new_mets{i}=strsplit(mets{j},' (')(1);
ans  = 
'Anteisopentadecanoylcardiolipin'
```

but I get:

```
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression
```

of course I can save it as a variable first and index in subsequently, but that is inefficient and there must surely be an easier way

Comment: what is the content of `mets`?

Comment: See answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to obtain only the first part:

```
new_mets{i} = regexp(mets{j}, '^.+(?= \()', 'match');
```

Example:

```
>> regexp('aaa (bb)', '^.+(?= \()', 'match')
ans = 
    'aaa'
```

---

Another approach:

```
ind = strfind(mets{j}, ' ('); %// find starting indices of matches
new_mets{i} = mets{1}(1:ind(1)-1); %// take substring previous to first match
```

Comment: if he does not want to use a temp variable in order to gain "efficiency", I doubt regexps will be accepted :)

Comment: @m.s. Yes, I read regexps can be slow... I don't know, I don't use them very much myself