# How to retrieve specific dimensions using size() function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, size

Here is an example matrix `A` of Dimensions `6x3x8x5`

Now if i use `size(A)`, i get all the dimensions as a row vector

```
ans = [6 3 8 5]
```

If i want to get specific dimension(singular), i could use something like `size(A,1)` or `size(A,3)` etc..

What if i want specified set of dimensions for eg, size of *3rd* and *4th* dimensions or *2nd* to *nth* dimension

What i want to do is something like `size(A,3:4)` or `size(A,2:n)` or `size(A,[1 3 4])`

But from the [**Doc**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html), it appears that, input dimensions for size could only be a scalar. When i try to do this, i get this error:

```
>> size(A,[2 3])
```

> Error using size
>   Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.

I'm expecting the output to be

```
ans = [3 8]
```

**FYI:**

I'm trying to pass this as an input argument into another function like this:

```
out = someFunction(arg1,arg2,size(A,[2 3]))
```

What i'm currently doing is

```
[~,size2,size3,~] = size(A)

out = someFunction(arg1,arg2,[size2, size3])
```

I just wanted to use it directly without the first line. Obviously when we have only two dimensions, we use it directly just by doing `size(A)`. why not in this case? Any alternative to make this a one-liner?

Comment: Short answer: yes, this is how it works. I don't see any problem with two lines myself. If you like, you might create your own modified `size` function that has the features you describe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

Comment: @thewaywewalk, although those solutions solve my problem, the questions are little different right?

Comment: No, they are duplicates. `size` is a function which returns an array, and you want to index it, without first assigning it to a local variable. You just gave a name to the "function" - the rest is equal :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk but `size` accepts parameter inputs as scalar but in the other question you cant do that.. for eg: you cant do `magic(5)(1)` but you could do `size(A,1)`. i just wanted to give input as vector instead of scalar. If you still think this question as a duplicate of that, i'll accept :)

Comment: I understand, but this is no option using `size`, which brings the duplicate question to the only possible solution. Just let the community decide, if it's duplicate or not :) You don't need to accept the duplicate suggestion

Comment: I shall wait then :) Also, (adding to my point). If MathWorks implements vector input for `size` function in any future release, these 2 questions will be completely different. Just saying ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the way `size` is written.

If you wanted a one-liner, you can use [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) to index the one-output form of `size`:

```
out = someFunction(arg1,arg2,...
              subsref(size(A),struct('type','()','subs',{{[2,3]}})));
```

And if you're going to be doing this a lot, add a function somewhere on the Matlab path or make an line one:

```
sizes = @(A,dims) subsref(size(A),struct('type','()','subs',{{dims}}));
out   = someFunction(arg1,arg2,sizes(A,[2,3]));
```

You can also create `sizes` without a *direct* call to `subsref` by a little indirection with function handles:

```
getSizes = @(d,s) d(s);
sizes    = @(A,s) getSizes(size(A),s);
```

which may be clearer and more maintainable.

Comment: Works great :) +1 i still don't understand the `subsref` function, even after reading the doc. How does it work? Could you pls elaborate it?

Comment: @SanthanSalai Basically, `subsref` is the function called whenever you index an array.  So if we have a matrix `A` and index it like `a15 = A(1,5)`, Matlab's interpreter/compiler (kind of) transforms that into `a15 = subsref(A,struct('type','()','subs',{{[1,5]}}))` in the background.

Comment: That makes some sense, so for `size` function you are doing that manually as MatLab doesn't do it by itself.. am i right?

Comment: @SanthanSalai  Yes.  The  Matlab language does not support the syntax `size(A)([2,3])` like some other languages do, so a call to `subsref` is the most direct way.  However, I have added a simpler version that avoids a direct call to `subsref` if it is more to your liking.  Also, if this answered your question, please accept it so the post is considered answered.

Comment: Alternate version is clever  :) i like them both.. thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 3):

Both [Troy Haskin's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) and mine are borrowed from this question: [**How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) I personally find the [**`getfield`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) approach appropriate for your case, where you just wrap `getfield` around your `size` function:

```
A = randn(1,2,3,4,5);   %// 5D double

out = getfield(size(A),{[2 3]})
```

---

```
out =

     2     3
```

Using `subsref` is probably the better approach as more direct and faster, but it could make your code less readable, as it is very specific hack.

Comment: yeah.. `getfield` is more readable. Also thanks for linking the original question. :)

Comment: Nice.  I'm feel silly not looking for this earlier now.