# One line standard basis vector creation

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to simplify the following two line process into a single line?

```
e = eye(n);
e = e(:,k);
```

Note: This gets the k-th n-dimensional standard basis vector.

Comment: Can I ask why? I fear that collapsing this into a single line has the potential to reduce readability, without any performance enhancement

Comment: I was just curious to see if there is a more elegant way to do this - however if it will reduce readability this will suffice! Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with two lines? If you don't mind getting a logical vector you can write: `e=((1:n)'==k)`. Or if you do mind: `e=double((1:n)'==k)`

Comment: @JensBoldsen you can just add `0` or else cast directly and still keep that as one line but of doubles instead of logicals

Comment: I do not see a reason why this would not be elegant enough.

Comment: Well, all the solutions for this problem are already detailed in the 2nd most frequent `Matlab` question : [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it). (This question is almost a duplicate actually). None of the solution is really "elegant", but you have quite a choice of options nonetheless.

Comment: @Hoki this question is about a specific operation and is not a duplicate at all in my opinion. The question asks for one line alternatives to a specific case, and three have already been proposed that would not apply to that general question linked to.

Comment: @Dan, I agree it is not enough a duplicate to be flagged as such, specially when new valid answers are already here. However, the link has some merit as this is somewhat just a "special case" of the more general question in the link (retrieve a subset of a returned variable). And all answers in the link will work for this question.

Comment: If you insist on having a one-liner, you could explicitly define `e = [zeros(1,k-1) 1 zeros(1,n-k)];`. But Dan's answer below is much more transparent, and possibly even faster (not that efficiency is really a problem here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matlab automatically pads zeros, you can use:

```
e([n,k])=[0,1]
```

Note that this line may produce wrong results when e already exists. To deal with the case `k=n`, `e(n)=0` comes first, then is overwritten by `e(k)=1`

Comment: Nice, but it makes a row vector. My money is still on Jens's comment answer.

Comment: Also for the `k==n` case just do `e(n)=1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about one line but this is a more (at least memory) efficient method:

```
e = zeros(n,1);
e(k) = 1;
```

Also if you're after elegance and readability then consider just encapsulating this into a function:

```
function e = basis_vector(n,k)
    e = zeros(n,1);
    e(k) = 1;
end
```