# Matlab indexing of function

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

Let's say I have a matrix A and want to calculate the standard deviation by using,
std(A,0,2). If I don't want to use the first row in further calculations, I can write somthing like B = std(A,0,2) and use B(2:end,:) but is there a way to make this a single statement something like std(A,0,2)(2:end,:)?

Comment: This question is related: [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

Comment: There are ways, but it's slower and ugly code. What's wrong with two lines? That's how Matlab works.