# Get multiple axes handles at once

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am looking for a one-liner to get multiple axes handles at once *in an object array* so that it can be passed into `linkaxes`. I am specifically looking for a single-line statement that does not use loops. I know I have done this in the past with a couple nested functions, but I can't figure out what I did.

The function `gca` can be used to get the axes handle for a specific figure, though this functionality does not appear to be documented. For example, call `gca(3)` to get the axis handle for Figure 3. I thought in the past I could call `gca([1:4])` to get all four axes handles, but that does not seem to work.

I know that I can use `get` by calling `get([1:4],'currentaxes')`, which returns a cell array of axes handles. However, I have not figured out a way to convert a cell array of objects into an object array.

I'm using MATLAB R2015a.

Comment: Are the figures and/or axes being generated in such a way that you can't store their handles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the answers already posted,  a possible one-line solution could be:

```
linkaxes(findobj('type','axes'))
```

it also allows implicitly prevent considering `figure` without `axes`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

After building the axes:

```
figure(1); axes();
figure(2); axes();
figure(3); axes();
```

one-liners are fun:

```
linkaxes(arrayfun(@(k) get(k,'CurrentAxes'), 1:3));
```

**Later Edit**

Apparently this works only for old-style graphics (in which the handle of a graphic object is a `double` number). The new handle graphics (being proper objects) cannot be accumulated in a single array by `arrayfun`:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html

*Maybe* the much simpler one-liner:

```
linkaxes(findobj(1:3,'Type','Axes'));
```

would work...

Comment: I'm told I need to set `'UniformOutput'` to be `false`, which results in a cell array, and therefore not compatible with `linkaxes`. Does this not happen to you?

Comment: @DavidK do you have figures without axes? If yes, remove them from the array (e.g. from 1:3).

Comment: @DavidK Also: does it work for the example code that I've given?

Comment: This doesn't work in MATLAB R2015b because: "matlab.graphics.axis.Axes output type is not supported. Set 'UniformOutput' to false.".

Comment: @CST-Link All figures have axes, and no, the example code does not work. I forgot to mention that I'm using 2015a

Comment: @DavidK I updated the answer. I'm curious if it works.

Comment: @DavidK Is not a competition, so it's fine. :-) I actually up-voted his answer after I posted my edit.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
cell_of_axes = get([1:4], 'currentaxes');
array_of_axes = [cell_of_axes{:}];
linkaxes(array_of_axes);
```

Comment: Hmm, that does work, and is certainly better than a for loop, though I was hoping for a single statement. That may not be possible though.

Comment: Yeah MATLAB syntax does not allow you to make that a one-liner as you can't add the {:} to the end of the call to get(...).

Comment: @ThomasIbbotson [that's not strictly true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to link a specific subset of axes and they are stored as objects in a cell:

```matlab
linkaxes([all_axes{:}], 'x');
```