# Distance from a known point to the edge of a web

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need help trying to figure out the matlab code for determination of the distance from a known point to the edges of the web seen in this figure [binary image of angiogenesis from a bead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9znu3.png). I know the precise point from previous code but I request any help in determination of the the distance from this point to any major edges seen in the image. Any ideas or input would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could just use the distance formula `dist=sqrt((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2);%%%%` Where `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` are coordinates of two pixels

Answer (score 0):

use MATLAB's edge function to detect edges in the image, and bwdist function to calculate the distance transform from the edges.
The distance transform image is basically a map, which contains at each pixel it's distance from the white pixels in the input image (in our case these are the edges of the image).

**Code**

Calculate the distance transform map

```
distMap = bwdist(edge(I));
```

Determine the distance of point P=(x,y) from the edges of I:

```
distFromP = distMap(y,x)
```

**One Liner solution**

By using the [method suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) it is possible to generate a one line code for calculating the distance of point P=(x,y) from the edges of I:

```
distFromP = subsref(bwdist(edges(I)),struct('type','()','subs',{{y,x}}));
```

**Specifying distance method**

You can also specify the distance function which you would like to use, by passing a method parameter (the default method is Euclidian), as can be seen in the following examples:

```
D1 = bwdist(im,'euclidean'); %euclidian distance sqrt(|y1-y2|^2+|x1-x2|^2)
D2 = bwdist(im,'cityblock'); %city block distance (|y1-y2|+|x1-x2|)
D3 = bwdist(im,'chessboard'); %chessboard (max(|y1-y2|,|x1-x2|)
D4 = bwdist(im,'quasi-euclidean'); %quasi-euclidean (for more information see MATLAB's documentation)
```