# How to sum up values in corresponding indexes of cells?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a `1x24` cell array called `chaining`, whose each cell contains a `119x119` matrix:

[image]

I want to find the sum of each corresponding elements of all the cells, and store them in a matrix called `result`. That is, the `(j,k)`th element of `result` should contains the sum of the `(j,k)`th elements of all the matrices in the cell array `chaining`.

The code I wrote to do this is:

```
for j=1:size(chaining,2)
    for k=1:size(chaining,2)
        result(j,k) = sum(chaining{1,:}(j,k));
    end
end
```

But this gives error because apparently MATLAB can't aggregate cell arrays for some reason (i.e., the `chaining{1,:}` part).

Could anyone please show me how to go about doing this?

Comment: using `j` as a variable name in Matlab [is not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).

Comment: @Shai Oh, resolving for complex numbers, got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
result = sum( cat(3, chaining{:}), 3 );
```

**What just happened here?**
First, we convert the cell array into a 3D array by "stacking" the 2D cell elements on the third dimension:

```
cat(3, chaining{:})
```

Once we have a 3D array of `size` 119-by-119-by-24 we can sum along the third dimension and get `result` of `size` 119-by-119:

```
sum( ..., 3 );
```

For more info see [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) help pages.

---

BTW,
If you insist on `chaining{1,:}(jj,kk)` type of solution (not recommended), you might find [`subsref` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628885/1714410) useful.