# How to chain indexing with function call

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have defined `f` and `t` as such

```
f = @(x)(x.^2);
t = [4,5,6];
```

Then I know that `f(t) = [16, 25, 36]` and I would expect to be able to write something like

```
f(t)(1)
```

to get `16` right away. As I noted, I can't. Is there a way to chain indexing right after a function call? Perhaps writing the indexing as a MATLAB function? i.e. if `l(4)` were just syntactic sugar for, say, `index(l, 4)` I would write `index(f(t), 1)`. Of course I can define such a function, but I am interested in knowing my options if I were to stick with already defined MATLAB functions and/or behavior.

Comment: MATLAB does not really natively support this but you can do it by overloading `subsref`. See this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it

Answer (score 1):

I hoped Matlab would be nice to have this feature like Python, but for some reason, it does not. Octave supports this though.