# How to use a cell array directly returned from a function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array, matrix-indexing

I have a path (without a file name at the end) as a string in Matlab and i want to receive the first parent directory (the directory after the last file seperator character) in it.

 At the moment i'm doing it like this:

```
>>filePath = 'D:\TRAIN_DATA\OBSTACLES\DOF';
>>firstParent = strsplit(filePath , filesep);
>>firstParent = firstParent{end};
>>disp(firstParent);
DOF
```

---

Is there any way i can use strsplit's return value (a cell array) without assinging it to a variable first?

 Something like:

```
>>filePath = 'D:\TRAIN_DATA\OBSTACLES\DOF';
>>firstParent = ( strsplit(filePath , filesep) ){end};
>>disp(firstParent);
DOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
[~,firstParent] = fileparts ( 'D:\TRAIN_DATA\OBSTACLES\DOF' )
```

Comment: Yes this solves the specific example i gave to my question. I can receive the first parent directory with this statement.
But there are other examples of this problem in my code that i'm actually trying to get the answer. 

Can i get the n. element of a cell array returned from a function like:
    
`nThElement = aFunctionThatReturnsACellArray(){n};`

Not like:

    `nThElement = aFunctionThatReturnsACellArray();

     nThElement  = nThElement{n};`

Comment: For the general case, I don't know of any _elegant_ way to do this without using an intermediate variable, but there are [a number of ugly or undocumented ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) such as using `subsref`, `getfield` or  intermediate functions.

Comment: There is no elegant way, it isn't a feature of the MATLAB language, parentheses `()` must be at the end of a statement if used. This is possible in Octave, but that's a whole other can of worms.