# Reshape of function defined matrices

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have the following code in matlab

```
deltax=@(t)xt(t).'-xt(t);
deltay=@(t)yt(t).'-yt(t);
deltaz=@(t)zt(t).'-zt(t);

deltar=@(t)reshape([deltax(:) deltay(:) deltaz(:)].',3*(100+1),[]).';
```

where `xt`, `yt`, `zt` are all well defined functions of `t`. If I do deltax(2), I get a column array with 101 entries and similarly for deltay(2) and deltaz(2).

However when I call

```
deltar(2)
```

I get this error

```
Input arguments to function include colon operator. To input the colon character, use ':' instead.
```

I have also tried

```
deltar=@(t)reshape([deltax(t)(:) deltay(t)(:) deltaz(t)(:)].',3*(100+1),[]).';
```

but this gives me syntax errors.

I must be doing some basic matlab mistake.

Comment: Not *exactly* a duplicate, but it's the same problem: `fcn(:)` calls `fcn` with argument '`:`', which is illegal (under most circumstances). What you need to do is something akin to your second attempt, but, that is illegal because this double-indexing is not allowed in MATLAB (it's allowed in Octave, though). You'll have to use `reshape(deltax(t),[],1)` for all three.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: That question provides an explanation for the error in the second attempt, and potential solutions (albeit less-than-optimal), but isn't really a duplicate. I think the problem here is just working out a better set of reshaping steps for the data.

Comment: @gnovice well, OK then :) *Related*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `deltax(t)` returns a matrix that you wish to reshape into a column, you can't do it with the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) due to having two sets of parentheses immediately following each other (a syntax error in MATLAB; more info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/52738)). You'd have to call [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) on each `delta(x|y|z)` return value individually:

```
deltar = @(t) reshape([reshape(deltax(t), [], 1) ...
                       reshape(deltay(t), [], 1) ...
                       reshape(deltaz(t), [], 1)].', 3*(100+1), []).';
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same reshaping of the data using [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) like so:

```
deltar = @(t) reshape(permute(cat(3, deltax(t), deltay(t), deltaz(t)), [3 1 2]), ...
                      3*(100+1), []).';
```

And if each `delta(x|y|z)` always returns a 101-by-M matrix, an even simpler solution is:

```
deltar = @(t) reshape([deltax(t).'; deltay(t).'; deltaz(t).'], [], 3*(100+1));
```