# Matlab access array element in one line

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

```
a = 0:99
s = size(a)
disp(s(2))
```

Can the last two lines be written as one? In other languages I am able to do f(x)[i], but Matlab seems to complain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case where you are using the [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function, you can add an additional argument to specify the dimension you want the size of, allowing you to easily do this in one line:

```
disp(size(a, 2));  % Displays the size of the second dimension
```

In the more general case of [accessing an array element without having to store it in a local variable first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/52738), things get [a little more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628885/52738), since MATLAB doesn't have the same kind of indexing shorthand you would find in other languages. [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), for example, would allow you to do `disp(size(a)(2))`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to collapse those two lines in one single statement and achieve a sort of `f(x)[i]` thanks to the functional form of the indexing operator: [**`subsref`**](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html).

```
disp(subsref(size(a), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {{2}})))
```

Comment: This answers the question, hence the upvote, but I would not recommend doing this, using two lines is a lot clearer! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I would opt for 2 lines – or `size(a, 2)` – as well... This one works but is very ugly.

Comment: I agree, this is formally exactly what I have asked for, as it turns out only to confirm I should not use it :D