# Function handle to a method in a constant property

Tags: matlab, oop, anonymous-function, handle

In R2018b, I have the following setup:

```
classdef SomeClass < handle    
    methods
        function SomeMethod(obj)
            disp in!
        end
    end    
end

classdef SomeOtherClass < handle

    properties (Constant)
        instance = SomeClass()
    end

    methods
        function Test(obj)
            hdl = @obj.instance.SomeMethod;
            hdl();            
        end
    end

end
```

However, running the `Test()` method gives an error:

```
>> SomeOtherClass().Test() 
Undefined function or variable 'obj.instance.SomeMethod'.
```

Changing the `Test()` method to:

```
function Test(obj)
    A   = obj.instance;
    hdl = @A.SomeMethod;
    hdl();
end
```

gives the desired result:

```
>> SomeOtherClass().Test
in!
```

I'm puzzled...why do I need the middle man `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @gnovice's finding:

```
>> obj = struct('instance', SomeClass());
>> hdl = @obj.instance.SomeMethod
hdl =
  function_handle with value:
    @obj.instance.SomeMethod

>> hdl(obj.instance)
Undefined function or variable 'obj.instance.SomeMethod'.

>> hdl()
Undefined function or variable 'obj.instance.SomeMethod'.
```

But:

```
>> instance=SomeClass();
>> hdl = @instance.SomeMethod
hdl =
  function_handle with value:
    @(varargin)instance.SomeMethod(varargin{:})

>> hdl(instance)
Error using SomeClass/SomeMethod
Too many input arguments.

Error in @(varargin)instance.SomeMethod(varargin{:})

>> hdl()
in!
```

Note how the function handle created in this second case is actually an anonymous function, which includes the object in it. This is a special case of the `@` operator, not the normal usage, which would be:

```
>> hdl=@SomeMethod
hdl =
  function_handle with value:
    @SomeMethod

>> hdl(instance)
in!
```

What this case actually does is create an anonymous function that embeds the object you intend to call this method on. You can create such a function this way:

```
>> hdl=@()obj.instance.SomeMethod()
hdl =
  function_handle with value:
    @()obj.instance.SomeMethod()

>> hdl()
in!
```

Comment: Great answer! Weird limitation though...doesn't make things more intuitive IMHO...Also you'd have to write the unwieldy  `@(varargin)obj.instance.SomeMethod(varargin{:})` just to get some arguments in...which kind of forces you to use the middle man. Oh well, we're [used to that from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/1085062) 

Comment: @Rody: you could consider submitting this as a bug to MahWorks. I agree that it makes little sense.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should. What version(s) did you try this on?

Comment: @Rody: I used R2018b.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer yet, but here's some more food for thought: you can recreate the same result using a [structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) in place of `SomeOtherClass`:

```
>> obj = struct('instance', SomeClass());
>> hdl = @obj.instance.SomeMethod;
>> hdl()
Undefined function or variable 'obj.instance.SomeMethod'.
```

I'm leaning towards this being a limitation of how the [function handle operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) works as opposed to the MATLAB class system.

Comment: I agree, it's the `@` operator that does unexpected things, it has nothing to do with the class system.