# How can I achieve cell array expansion as a function call in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have the following cell array:

```
>> tmp0 = {'foo', '%s', 'one'; 'bar', '%d', 3}

tmp0 =

  2×3 cell array

    'foo'    '%s'    'one'
    'bar'    '%d'    [  3]
```

I can use it like this with `sprintf`:

```
>> sprintf('%s,%d', tmp0{:,3})

ans =

    'one,3'
```

I would like to be able to achieve the same thing with a function call, since if I have a function that generates a cell array, say `genCell()`, I don't think I can achieve something like `genCell(){:}` in MATLAB.

So I made this function:

```
function cellExp(cellIn)
  cellIn{:}
end
```

Although dubious it seems to work as expected so far, since calling `cellExp(tmp0(:,3))` seems to be the same as calling `tmp0{:,3}`

```
>> cellExp(tmp0(:,3))

ans =

    'one'


ans =

     3


>> tmp0{:,3}

ans =

    'one'


ans =

     3
```

However, ultimately, I cannot use it as desired:

```
>> sprintf('%s,%d', cellExp(tmp(:,3)))
Error using cellExp
Too many output arguments.
```

Comment: I don't think this is doable. You need to pass a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of arguments to `sprintf`, but a function can't return that. Even if your function uses [variable output arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html), you still have to explicitly get them all (i.e. it doesn't just dump them all as a comma-separated list). I don't think there's a very good way around using a temporary variable here. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/52738)

Answer (score 1):

The last error message you are getting is because the output of `cellExp(tmp0(:,3))` is [comma-separeted list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for here, but I think this is one possibility for a function that will return your string based on a `myCell = tmp0`.

```matlab
function myStr = mySprintf(myCell)

formatSpec = strjoin(myCell(:,2), ',');
[A1, A2] = myCell{:, 3};
myStr = sprintf(formatSpec, A1, A2);

end
```

Comment: No, `cellExp` has no output. It displays its input to the console, but doesn't define any output arguments.