# concatenation of the arrayfun output

Tags: matlab

Assuming that

```
outputTemp =

  2×1 cell array

    {122×1 string}
    {220×1 string}
```

`finalOutput` is a string array (`342x1 string`).

is there any way to do the following

```
outputTemp = arrayfun(@(x)someFunc(x), someInput, 'UniformOutput', false)';
finalOutput= [outputTemp{1}; outputTemp{2}];
```

in one line?

for the minimal example, `someFunc` can be a function that provides the names of the files in folders provided in `someInput`.

Comment: it is and it is detailed in the question.

Comment: I see, I guess for using `cat` you would need another line, have you checked `cell2mat(arrayfun(...))`?

Comment: "CELL2MAT does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects."

Comment: Why does it need to be on one line? Is that really worth making stuff totally unreadable? Maybe there is a different solution to your problem that doesn’t require putting all of this on one line. Please share your actual problem!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. Here is a MWE:

```
str1 = ["Test";"Test1";"42"]
str2 = ["new test";"pi = 3"]
C = {str1;str2}

ConCatStr = [C{1};C{2}];
```

This should answer the question regarding concatnation of string-arrays. Note that this is only possible with real strings (not with char-arrays). It is hard to tell, what you are doing beforehand as there are not details about `getFilesFilt()` and `mainFolderCUBX`.

**EDIT** MVE for the updated question

```
% function that returns a matrix
fnc = @(x)[x,1];
% anonymous function that returns a vector
fnc2 = @(x)reshape(fnc(x),2,1)

tmp = arrayfun(@(x)fnc(x), rand(10,1),'UniformOutput',false)
```

Answer: there is no proper way. However, you can do a little bit of fiddling and force everything into a single line (making the code ugly and less efficient)

```
tmp = arrayfun(@(x)fnc(x), rand(10,1),'UniformOutput',false);
out = reshape(cell2mat(tmp),numel(cell2mat(tmp)),1);
```

just replace the `tmp` with what is written with it.

Comment: My question was not phrased correctly, please review the question again and see if you can answer it. Your current answer is just a copy-paste of my code...

Comment: I am still missing a MVE. Regarding the requirement of 1-line command: In gerneal, no. Though the type-fun functions can return two arguments (e.g. if you say `arrayfun(@max,array)` it will return the maximum and the index as a second argument), there is no proper way in phrasing a non-uniform output directly into a single output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code using `cat()` + `subsref()`, i.e.,

```
finalOutput= cat(1,subsref(arrayfun(@(x)someFunc(x), someInput, 'UniformOutput', false),struct('type', '{}', 'subs', {{:}})));
```

**Example**

```
S(1).f1 = rand(3,5);
S(2).f1 = rand(6,10);
S(3).f1 = rand(4,2);

cat(1,subsref(arrayfun(@(x) mean(x.f1)',S,'UniformOutput',false),struct('type', '{}', 'subs', {{:}})))
```

such that

```
ans =

   0.89762
   0.53776
   0.42440
   0.25272
   0.58197
   0.34503
   0.40259
   0.41792
   0.43527
   0.53974
   0.49976
   0.63342
   0.36539
   0.58541
   0.57042
   0.60914
   0.60851
```

Comment: is it one-liner? does it save me a line?

Comment: @GideonKogan what's your "someInput" and "someFunc()"? if no details, hard for others to give you one-liner command

Comment: it looks like it would work on python but your example does not work on my version. what is your version of the matlab?

Comment: @GideonKogan I just ran it over Octave, not on MATLAB yet

Comment: please try on matlab

Comment: @GideonKogan I don't have MATLAB on my laptop. I just want give you some ideas how to make it, but maybe you need to adapt it on your MATLAB. What's your MATLAB version?

Comment: 2019a. I am familiar with this idea from python. it does not work on matlab. otherwise, there would be no questions

Comment: @Irreducible what's is your Matlab version?

Comment: 2018b, I am not aware that matlab supports function calls like these: `myfun(arg){:}`

Comment: sorry I think you missunderstood, I said: This WONT work on Matlab, also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

Comment: @Irreducible thanks for the link you leave in the comments. I updated my answer using `subsref`, so could you check if it works now?

Comment: it seems that `getfield` cant handle the colon operator (`{:}`), you get the following error `Invalid use of operator`

Comment: @Irreducible well....I cannot check it out by myself since I have no Matlab....but thank you any way