# Accessing the first index of an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, array-indexing

If I have an anonymous function in MATLAB, say

```
f = @(t) [t, t+5];
```

and I wanted to create a new anonymous function g that accesses the first index of `f`, so that, in this example,

```
g = @(t) t;
```

how can I do so?

I have tried doing something along the lines of

```
g = @(t) f(t)(1);
```

but the compiler says that this is "invalid array indexing", even though I thought that this would basically allow `g` to be `g(t) = t`

Comment: What about `g = f(1)`? `f` appears to be an array of function handles, logically I'd assume you simply index into that

Comment: Unfortunately. I believe that g = f(1) actually gives the array [1, 6] to g. So essentially, g = f(1) means g = [1, 1 + 5]

Comment: I _think_ this is a duplicate of this slightly more generic question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it and your answer is basically [Vugar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322659/3978545)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have resolved this. One can do the following:

f = @(t) [t, t+5];

first = @(t) t(1);

next = @(t) first(f(t));