# Is there a functional form in Matlab to get the same result as A{:}?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I understand this is a classic question and some aspects of it have been answered before, for instance here: [How can I index a MATLAB array returned by a function without first assigning it to a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it)

But reading through the comments it has become clear that i) some of the proposed solutions don't work anymore (the ones based on builtin or feval) or ii) don't work for certain classes or indices.

Specifically for a cell array A, the results of `A{:}` and `subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'}))` are not the same.

For the sake of completeness, I'd like to point out that `cell2mat(A)` is not the same as `A{:}` and does not help either.

To clarify further why this is relevant, if A was just a variable there would be no need for `subsref`. However, if A is a more general expression such as `B{1}` or `C(1)` etc, Matlab does not let you further index it with `{:}`.

A minimal working example showing the problem:

```
A=arrayfun(@(x) rand(2,2,2),ones(3,1),'Uni',0)
cat(4,A{:})
```

compared to:

```
cat(4,subsref(arrayfun(@(x) rand(2,2,2),ones(3,1),'Uni',0),substruct('{}',{':'})))
```

which only works on the first element.

Comment: It depends on how the result of `A{:}` will by consumed. If you need just one output you can use out `out = a{:}`. If you need more outputs use this `[out1,out2]=A{:}`.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish. In a comment below you state that “The point is that A is only a placeholder for a general Matlab expression, such as a function […]”. So please clarify why you need to expand the cell output of a function into a comma-separated list. What do you want to feed this list into? What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: Minimal working example added. Hth.

Comment: Your MRE can be implemented as `rand(2,2,2,3)`, so not really a great example for your problem. On the other hand, this seems to be a case of “I prefer one really complex, unreadable line of code over two simple lines.” I hope this is not the case!

Answer (score 2):

I tested in R2019b and `subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'}))` seems to return the same as `A{:}`, namely, a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the contents of the cell array. However, since `subsref` is a function, you need to specify how many outputs you want; by default it only provides the first one. Compare:

```
>> A = {'xy', [10 20 30]};

>> A{:}
ans =
    'xy'
ans =
    10    20    30

>> subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'}))
ans =
    'xy'

>> [a, b] = subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'}))
a =
    'xy'
b =
    10    20    30
```

Comment: That's a very helpful clarification. However, in order to make this work I would have to know beforehand how many elements there will be in the cell array and then manually assign each one of them into a separate variable using the multiple LHS syntax.How can I assign the result into one variable?
Specifically what I am really trying to do is feed the result into the cat() function:
`cat(4,subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'})))`

Comment: Dare I ask why you can't just use `{:}` if you want to do `cat(4,A{:})`? Maybe you actually want to `reshape(A, ...)`?

Comment: I could of course just do `cat(4,A{:})`. The point is that A is only a placeholder for a general Matlab expression, such as a function, and I probably don't have to reiterate Matlab's most infamous limitation, which is that you cannot for some reason combine functions and indexing of any kind.

Comment: In which case including a [mcve] in your question would help clarify the actual desired behaviour, because maybe you can still use `reshape`, or something else which squashes your result into the 4th dimension instead of whatever it's doing at the minute, without having to do any syntactic tricks to step around how MATLAB is normally written.

Comment: @M-G-K I updated my answer (see last part) now that it's clearer to me what you want

Comment: @luis-mendo Thanks a lot. I appreciate your insightful and constructive replies! Your updated reply solves the concrete problem at hand, but I have to admit that I had hoped for a more general solution. What is the conceptual difference? Why are the two outputs different? Aren't both comma separated lists?

Comment: @M-G-K The two outputs form the comma-separated list. That is, the list _is_ those two outputs, _without them being packed_ into an array. So when you do an assignment, only the first output is used. It's as if you type `x = 10, 20`: `x` gets the `10`, and the `20` is not used. To use the two numbers you coud write `[x, y] = deal(1, 2)`. Note that you need `deal` here. However, with comma-separated-lists [_generated from a cell array_](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) `deal` is [not needed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)

Comment: @luis-mendo Thanks for the links. But unfortunately I didn't find any solution that would make a function return a comma separated list of arbitrary length, which is what A{:} or any such construction is returning. I believe, and please correct me if I am wrong, because this seems to be at the core of the problem, that functions will always return a predefined number of elements because of the nargin/varargin mechanism.

Comment: @M-G-K No, a Matlab function doesn't return a _predefined_ number of elements. The number of returned elements depends on the way you _call_ it. In the example in my answer, compare `[a, b] = subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'}))` (returns two elements) and `a = subsref(A,substruct('{}',{':'}))` (returns one). The actual problem is that a comma-separated list is not an "object", but rather a collection of them, not wrapped into a higher-level object (array). In other words, a function returning several outputs is the same as the function returning a comma-separated list of them

Comment: @M-G-K I think I see the problem with my `cellmat` line: if you replace `A` with a function call such as `foo(a,b)`, it only returns _one_ output. To get the full set of, say, three outputs you need an explicit `[x, y, z] = foo(a,b)`; or `outs = cell(1,3); [outs{:}] = foo(a,b)`. Please confirm that that line is not useful for you and I will delete it from my answer

Comment: @luis-mendo Yes, that is exactly the problem. A function call used as an argument to another function, such as in the cell2mat example above, will always only return the first element of the list. It is predefined in the sense that you have to decide at the time of the call how many return elements you request instead of leaving it to the function. And that is fundamentally different to the way A{:} will return its value(s).

Comment: @M-G-K I see. On one hand, `A{:}` behaves like the function call, in the sense that the number of returned values depends on the number of outputs in the call or in the left-hand-side of the assignment. For example, with `A = {'xy', [10 20 30]}` you can do `[a, b] = A{:}` or `a = A{:}` to make `A{:}` return either two or elements or one. On the other hand, the number of elements returned by default, i.e. when called without outputs, is different: a function call returns one value by default, whereas `A{:}` returns all of them by default

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" here (if there is one) is that there is no single variable in MATLAB that can hold all the elements of a comma-separated list. Following on from @Luis' answer, you *could* do this:

```matlab
A = {'xy', [10 20 30]};
[x{1:numel(A)}] = subsref(A, substruct('{}', {':'}))
```

but... it achieves precisely nothing, because you've just put all the elements of the comma-separated list back into a single `cell` array, which is precisely where you started.

So, I suppose the point is that a comma-separated list probably isn't much use to you here. What do you *actually* want to do?

Comment: To make it clear, if A was just a variable, there would not be a problem. But if A is an expression, such as `B{1}` or a function `C(x)` Matlab doesn't let you index it, as I am sure you are aware of.