# Capture all possible outputs based on variable number of inputs.

Tags: matlab, variables, capture

I would like Matlab to return all the outputs from a variable input function. For instance,

[varargout]=cpd_intersect(varargin{:});

This only returns the last output  but I know the function is defined to give multiple outputs.

Instead of defining dummy variables A, B , C etc in [A,B,C...]=pd_intersect(varargin{:}). I would like something like a cell to store all the output values based on the input number of values. I hope this makes sense. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a MATLAB function returns a variable number of values, how can I get all of them as a cell array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821644/if-a-matlab-function-returns-a-variable-number-of-values-how-can-i-get-all-of-t)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is late, but I think this is what you want:

```
function [varargout] = myfun(f, varargin)
% apply f to args, and return all its outputs

[ x{1:nargout(f)} ] = f(varargin{:}); % capture all outputs into a cell array
varargout = x;                        % x{:} now contains the outputs of f
```

The insight here is that

1. `NARGOUT` can operate on functions and returns their maximum number of outputs
2. using `[ X{1:2} ] = ...`on the left hand side when X is undefined, is equivalent to doing `[ X{1} X{2} ] = ...`, and can capture 2 separate outputs into individual variables.

Two points to note:

1. this works for anonymous functions too! e.g. `@(x)eig(x)`
2. it won't work for functions that use `varargout`, i.e. functions with truly variable numbers of outputs. If this is the case then there should be a way to calculate how many outputs you are going to have, e.g. using `nargin`.

PS I learnt this from @gnovice, [If a MATLAB function returns a variable number of values, how can I get all of them as a cell array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821644/if-a-matlab-function-returns-a-variable-number-of-values-how-can-i-get-all-of-t)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by returning a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html?s_tid=doc_12b)

Comment: Maybe I am not asking the right way but I cannot preallocate memory to a cell array of unknown size. I just want to force all outputs based on number of inputs.

Answer (score -1):

I see you cannot force a variable comma separated output list in Matlab. Pity. It would be useful. It seems I have to explicitly assign each output. This sucks since I do not know beforehand the number of outputs I will get.

Comment: Yes, this is not possible without knowing the number of outputs beforehand.

Comment: I think it is possible using `nargout(FUNC)` - see my answer